# dlib not using CUDA even after confirmation that it would during build

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, dlib, cudnn

I am attempting to get dlib to use CUDA on Ubuntu. I know that the hardware is capable. I already have CUDA and cuDNN.

I got dlib from the git repo and ran the following:

```
cd build
cmake .. -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/local/cuda
cmake . --build
```

The build process said that dlib found cuda and cuDNN, and that dlib will use cuda, but when I run a python shell, and type

```
import dlib
dlib.DLIB_USE_CUDA
```

it returns False.

I am not sure why this happens. I am using python3 by the way. I also already installed dlib via pip3, and am not sure if I am using the wrong one.

Comment: Your question seems to be a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51943050/dlib-not-using-cuda)

Answer (score 0):

From the dlib creator website:

[I compiled dlib's Python interface with CUDA enabled, why isn't it using CUDA?](http://dlib.net/faq.html#Whywon'tthePythonbindingscompilework)